# How to change the Provider name in Huawei AppGallery?

Tags: android, huawei-developers, appgallery

I uploaded an app to Huawei AppGallery. In about section of the app there are two fields called Developer & Provider. I was able to change the Developer name from **Developer center > Settings > My profile**. But only the Developer name has changed & my real name is still showing as the Provider name. How can I change the Provider name? According to the information provided by Huawei developers website [here](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/start/nickname-settings-0000001053785448) both of these names should be changed when we change the Developer name. But it didn't work for me. Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Could you please try to change the Legal entity name? It seems to correspond to the provider name.

Comment: Have you changed the provider name before? In addition, you can send the screenshot of the page to hmscore@huawei.com, and type the necessary information.

Comment: Hi Changer, if your issue has not been resolved yet, please let me know : your appid, developer's name and the provider's name you want to change to and the screenshot, you can send them to: developer_dtse@Futurewei.com. I will check the issue from HW AGC internally. thanks

Comment: Thanks both of you for your help. my problem has been solved now. After about 2 days Provider name has updated on AppGallery. It looks like AppGallery takes few days to update these information.

Comment: Great to know Changer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like AppGallery takes few days to update these information. After about 2 days my Provider name has been updated successfully.